# Android Realm asynchronous architecture in app with Activities & Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, architecture, realm

I've been using `Realm` with UI thread writes until I found out the UI was unusable at some point with significant database volume.

I'm now trying to figure out how to properly orchestrate asynchronous writes in app with activities and fragments showing data list and screens to enter the data.

At this moment, my problem is:

I have an `Activity A`, with its own `Realm` instance, listing data and listening to realm changes to update itself.
If I want to add more data, I create an `Activity B` with its own `Realm` instance.

I've started listening to the `onSuccess` callback of the transaction to `refresh()` the `Realm` instance in order to trigger Realm listeners and have `Activity A` update itself. Unfortunately it doesn't work when I quickly go back to activity A because the Realm of `Activity B` is closed and `onSuccess` is not getting called.

At this point I'm not sure how should I organize all this. I see the option where I don't create `Activity B` and use fragments but having to do this everywhere in my app doesn't feel great and might be error prone.

What's the best practice for this use case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You store the RealmResults as a field, and you add a RealmChangeListener to get updates.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Updates aren't triggered using `executeTransactionAsync` as the provided Realm is not auto-refreshing. Doing a `Realm.refresh()` when the transaction completes works, but when my activity finishes the Realm is closed on the onSuccess is not called.

Comment: The question isn't very clear, and why you're doing the things described is also unclear. Realm has all of the functions needed to listen for changes, and moreover Realm objects are live updating; a Results object always reflects the underlying data. It's also not clear what every activity would have it's own Realm - if activities are related, it would make sense to store them within a single Realm. Can you take a look at the documentation [React To Changes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/react-to-changes/) and then maybe update the question with your use case?

Comment: The Realm auto-refreshes if the Realm is on a looper thread, such as the UI thread. If you have a Realm open on a non-looper background thread, well, don't expect updates - then transactions or refresh force version updates. Or closing all instances then reopening. Version retention is an issue. However, you can't even call `executeTransactionAsync` from a non-looper thread, so it is impossible that it "doesn't update". However, updates are evaluated asynchronously, and delivered via RealmResults's RealmChangeListener. So you should use a change listener.

Comment: I've solved this by sharing only one Realm instance between my activities